# Error in a codechef question, checked the test cases manually, doesnt show any error at that time

Tags: python

```
m = list(input().split(" "))
a = int(m[0])
b = float(m[1])
if(a%5==0 and a<b):
    y = (b-a-0.50)
    print('%.2f' %y)
else:
    print(b)
```

Typed this code and checked the three test cases in the question, didnt get an error but it shows an error while submitting.

> Pooja would like to withdraw X $US from an ATM. The cash machine will only accept the transaction if X is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal the bank charges 0.50 $US. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.

Q : https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

Comment: Hint: what should happen when a = 120, b = 120.25?

Comment: Also, you are printing an unformatted `float` in the `else`. You should `print(m[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your else statement, you aren't putting two digits after the decimal point:

```
    print('%.2f' %b)
```

Also, you need to make sure that your balance can handle the transaction AND the fee:

```
m = list(input().split(" "))
a = int(m[0])
b = float(m[1])
if(a%5==0 and a + 0.5 <= b):
    y = (b-a-0.50)
    print('%.2f' %y)
else:
    print('%.2f' %b)
```